# Aws Build Pipeline for Grails 4

Tags: amazon-web-services, grails, devops, aws-code-deploy

Deploy code is failing in the Deployment stage for Grails
I have shown the code in buildspech.yml

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      java: corretto11
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo "Entered Pre Build Phase"
  build:
    commands:
      - echo "Entered Build Phase"
      - echo "Copy Client Complete"
      - gradle assemble
      - echo "Assemble complete"
#      - cd server/build/libs
#      - echo "Inside Folder"
#      - unzip *.war
#      - rm *.war

  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo "Entered Post Build Phase"
artifacts:
  files:
     - server/build/**/*
```

I have tried Files build/lib/**/* as well

[image]

Comment: Have you checked `Details` of your deploy for any extra info?

Comment: Deployment completed, but with errors: During an aborted deployment, some instances may have deployed the new application version. To ensure all instances are running the same version, re-deploy the appropriate application version. Failed to deploy application. Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-01296e306e4b65252'. Aborting the operation. [Instance: i-01296e306e4b65252] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: Engine execution has encountered an error.. Instance deployment failed. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'.

Comment: It is showing this in details.

Comment: During an aborted deployment, some instances may have deployed the new application version. To ensure all instances are running the same version, re-deploy the appropriate application version.

Comment: I have redeployed changing version

Comment: any insights on the issue? @user2253081